# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

Component take user from service with params

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    providers: [UserService],
    template: `
    <p>{{user.id}}</p>
`
})
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit  {
    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.userService.getUser(id)
                .then(user => {console.log(user.id);this.user = user})
        });
    }
```

Service :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private postUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/user-detail/';  // URL to web api
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {

        return this.http.get(this.postUrl+id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as User)
            .catch(this.handleError);

    };
```

And I get Error `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./UserPageComponent class UserPageComponent - inline template:1:7 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

It looks as if the service does not send the promise, although it should.
How to solve this proble?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks like your component doesn't have default value for user, so it is undefined when component rendered try adding default value

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    providers: [UserService],
    template: `
    <p>{{user.id}}</p>
`
})
export class UserPageComponent implements OnInit  {
    user = {} // default value for user

    constructor(
        private userService: UserService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {};

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            let id = +params['id'];
            this.userService.getUser(id)
                .then(user => {console.log(user.id);this.user = user})
        });
    }
```

actually it will be better to add some conditional logic here then

```
<p *ngIf="user">{{user.id}}</p>
```

it should work

Comment: You may as well add a conditional(ternary operator) denoted by the question mark symbol ?. This expression {{user.id}} will execute only if the condition is truthy